# Formula of cooling power of compressed air

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas, air

For my blog on Trompe air compressors I am looking into uses that people could have with these compressors if they build one themselves (for big versions see this [Ragged Chute Trompe](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvgNqIuz2GM)).

One of the uses of unlimited isothermally compressed air is the cooling effect one can achieve by releasing it through a valve. Yet I have no clue what bar level of compressed air in what volume can achieve that amount of cooling, so this is what I am trying to find out.

I have found the [Gas Laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gas_laws), for ideal situations. Also I fount the [Joule-Thomson effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joule%E2%80%93Thomson_effect), yet I am no physics expert. I'm willing to do research, but the formulas are dancing in front of my eyes. And I lost track of what is needed to solve this.

As I understand the ideal gas situation there is a set temperature a gas his temperature falls when released. This is not an ideal gas, it's air (let's say Nitrogen (78%), Oxygen (21%), Argon (1%), Carbon-dioxide (0.03%) and water vapor). On top of this, the released air needs to go somewhere after it is released (yet I would feel comfortable not to take this in to consideration for this formula). Furthermore I'm looking to answer this question for flexible situations so I can give people 'a' idea of that they might achieve.

So I'm looking for a formula using the following parameters (only space pressure is fixed):

Compressed air [bar]

Compressed air volume [m3] (continuously replenished)

Compressed air temperature [C°]

Space [m3]

Space Temperature [C°]

Space pressure [1 bar]

Is this possible to even make such a formula? I was checking refrigerators but they reuse the coolant, and the coolant is Tetrafluoroethane I gather so not the same as air that is not reused. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The appropriate formulas are those describing something called the *bell coleman cycle*, which uses air as the working fluid and where the desired output is that very same air that runs the cycle. It's all been worked out in great detail because most airliners with turbine engines use it for air conditioning, in devices called *air packs*.

Comment: oo cool, I will check it out. do you have a working example?

Comment: Oo wow, I think Wolfram has a calculator. I am assuming the high pressure and low pressure are the pressure of the compressed air and the pressure after releasing the air. This Heat capacity ratio is still an enigma to me after scanning the wiki. Will check it out thank you! https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FormulaRepository/resources/Bell-Coleman-Cycle